# headers set in caps with \titleps

Tags: header-footer

For some reason I cannot set the headers in capital letters with the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{Brill}[]{
\sethead[\thepage][\chaptertitle][]
{}{\chaptertitle}{\thepage}
\setheadrule{0pt}}

\pagestyle{Brill}


\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter 1}

I'm the fairest of them all.
\newpage
I'm the fairest of them all.
\newpage
I'm the fairest of them all.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\MakeUppercase\chaptertitle`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It is not enough feedback `;-)`. It works for me though.

Comment: Where do you put this in the code?

Comment: `\sethead[\thepage][\MakeUppercase\chaptertitle][]
{}{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitle}{\thepage}`

Comment: Just my opinion, but  small caps would look better. All caps is generally too big (unledd you use the `\small` size).

Answer (score 1):

Although you could use `\MakeUppercase`, as suggested in comments, it's safer to load the [`textcase`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcase) package and use `\MakeTextUppercase` instead (in case, eventual math contents or `\ref`s or `\cite`s go in the title):

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{textcase}

\newpagestyle{Brill}[]{%
  \sethead[\thepage][\MakeTextUppercase{\chaptertitle}][]
          {}{\MakeTextUppercase{\chaptertitle}}{\thepage}%
  \setheadrule{0pt}%
}

\pagestyle{Brill}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}
I'm the fairest of them all.
\newpage
I'm the fairest of them all.
\newpage
I'm the fairest of them all.

\end{document}
```

An image of the result, showing the header:

[image]

Comment: Muchas gracias Gonzalo.